# TypeError: Cannot read property 'created' of undefined, error 'Vue' is not defined Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

i'm trying to use Custom Directives in vue.js 3 from the documentation, and i use the example that in the documentation but **i've these errors:**

- 'Vue' is not defined.

**and when i remove "vue" from the Directive code these errors show in the console:**

- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'created' of undefined
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

I think these error cuz i use vue version 3 but i'm using Custom Directives that in Vue vesion 3 from documentation

main js:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./scss/main.scss";
import "normalize.css";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");

//Directive

const app = vue.createApp({})
app.directive('highlight', {
    beforeMount(el, binding) {
        el.style.background = binding.value
    }
})
```

component:

```
<p v-highlight="'yellow'" class="content">{{ limit(content,90, 'more...') }}</p>
```

Could you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no object or function called `vue` in Vue 3 , to register a global directive just you the app instance already defined like :

```
...
const app=createApp(App)
app.use(store).use(router).mount("#app");

app.directive('highlight', {
    beforeMount(el, binding) {
        el.style.background = binding.value
    }
})
```